# Grep two lines with unique keyword

Tags: unix, grep, logfiles

I would like to take a txt file and do some sort of grep command and save the output to a file to be used in R. 
Consider I have the following from a log file:

```
current_t: 178.027

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

rv: -8.421698E-06

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at ModelActions.Update () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Filename:  Line: -1)

 current_t: 179.7662

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

rv: -8.413203E-06

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
```

I want to be able to grab each line that has current_t and rv. Preferably I would I like to have it output as:

```
178.027  -8421698E-06
179.7662  -8.413203E-06
```

where all times are placed in a column and rv are placed in the following column. Is there a grep command for me to do something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F: '$1~/current_t/{ct=$2} $1~/rv/{print ct, $2}' file          

 178.027  -8.421698E-06
 179.7662  -8.413203E-06
```

assumes your data has always matching pairs.

Comment: Wow awesome, that did the trick! Whats the best place to get documentation on this kind of stuff?